# Regex not work correctly in array

Tags: c#, regex

I want to able to search through folders and subfolder names, then if they have a specific pattern on their name, change or remove them from the folder name.
I used the below code but `folderNameList` return `{}`

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(myRootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


string findFolderNamePattern = @"((?i)mydomain.com|sitename(?-i))";
string replacement = " ";
Match folderNameList = Regex.Match(dirs.ToString(), findFolderNamePattern);

                foreach (var folder in folderNameList.ToString())
                {
                    folder = Regex.Replace(folder.ToString(), replacement);
                }
```

Also you can see the regex  [here](https://regex101.com/r/pCljcB/2)

Comment: why are you `ToString`ing `dirs`? That won't give you what you want.

Comment: The same for `folderNameList`.

Comment: because it gets an error  `cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'`

Comment: When you use dirs.ToString() as the input to your RegEx you're effectively searching against the string "System.String[]".  You probably meant to run the RegEx for each item in the list instead?

Comment: Even if you could do this, strings are immutable meaning that `folder = "whatever"` won't change the source list.

Comment: Avoid modifying the variable "folder" in foreach loop. use other name. see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a90c87be-9553-4d48-9892-d482ee325f02/why-cant-change-value-in-foreach?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(myRootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string findFolderNamePattern = @"((?i)mydomain.com|sitename(?-i))";
string replacement = " ";            

foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    var newFolder = Regex.Replace(directory, findFolderNamePattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works when I used to debug, it returns folder names. but never change their name at all!

Comment: @D.JCode What do you mean by "never change their name at all"? in debug what do you see in `newFolder` after `Regex.Replace`? The same value as in `directory`?